# PHP: Parse JSON and square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using PHP, how I can I parse a JSON object with an array given in square brackets and delimited by a pipe "|"?

For example, I need to access the second component of the "Data", in this case "English". 
Assume the lengths are variable, so you cannot slice by character positions.

```
{"Username":"5018",
 "Data":["53094185|English|USA|2012-07-24 12:49:00|AZ|"],
 "Location":"New York"}
```

Comment: The value corresponding to the key of `"Data"` is an array with a single string element. JSON doesn't care about string delimiters. Grab the string, `split` it, and move on.

Comment: Thanks Jack - but what is the actual syntax, I can't seem to get it to actually print out the "Data" array, or any piece of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple:

```
$X = json_decode($JSON);
$arr = explode('|', $X->Data[0]);
print_r($arr)
```

Comment: Thanks Max, but the code doesn't work:  <?php


$jsontest = '{"Username":"5018", 
              "Data":["53094185|English|USA|2012-07-24 12:49:00|AZ|"], 
              "Location":"New York"}';

echo $jsontest;

$parsed = json_parse($jsontest); 
$arr = explode('|', $parsed['Data']);
print_r($arr);

?>

Comment: it should work fine now I misspelled a function name. It was ```json_decode``` not ```json_parse```. Tested it now!

Answer (score 0):

json_decode it.  You will still need to split up the data array value string as this is just a simple string in JSON.